# Is it possible to transfer spreadsheet data into a property list?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, property-list

I want to bundle some pre-loaded data with an iOS app. I have some raw data but that's edited in the spreadsheet. Is there any way to transfer this data into property list (.plist) format without manually inputting it?

Comment: The short answer is yes you can import the data from the spread  sheet with out re-typing it. But to better help you we need to know how the data layed out in the spread sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export 2 columns from the spreadsheet in XML format, then programatically read the XML file and use the **NSPropertyListSerialization** class to de-serialize the raw XML data:

```
NSData *pListDataAsXML = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"xmlFileName.xml"];
id pListData = (id)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:pListDataAsXML
                                                    mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                              format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                    errorDescription:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial to get your preload data into plist.May be it will help you.

[this link](http://richardwarrender.com/2010/09/spreadsheet-to-plist/)